# How do I clear a flask session?

Tags: python-2.7, flask

While importing flask, we import modules such as `session` etc.

`SecureCookieSession` is a kind of dictionary, that can be accessed using session.

Now, I try to clear all the junk variables that I used while trying to build a website.

One of the answers on stackoverflow used a command like `session.clear()` for clearing the contents of a session. But such a command gives an error that no such command exists.

Can anyone point out for me how to clear the `SecureCookieSession` and how to clear the session every time I shutdown the server or close the website?

Comment: You might want to re-think about which answer you accept.

Answer (score -44, accepted):

<del>There is no way to `clear` session or anything.</del>

One must simply change the `app.config["SECRET_KEY"]` and the contents in session dictionary will get erased.

Comment: As posted below, the session can be cleared using `session.clear()` and including this import `from flask import session`

Comment: Doing that will invalidate all your visitors cookies at once and force them to re-login

Comment: Instead of voting down this post, let's make it better everyone! The point to reset the secret key is a valid point!

Answer (score 122):

```
from flask import session

session.clear()
```

I use session like this with flask, it does work.
I don't use `SecureCookieSession` though, but maybe it can help.

Comment: **Note:** If you are also using flashed messages in your application, you should consider that flashed messages are stored in the session and can, therefore, be erased before they are flashed if you clear the session.

Comment: we can do this in an active request context only right?

Comment: @GautamJain, yes! Otherwise you will get a runtime error for "working outside of request context"

Answer (score 28):

You can also iterate through the session and call `session.pop()` for each key in your session. Pop will remove the variable from the session and you don't have to keep updating your secret key.

```
for key in list(session.keys()):
     session.pop(key)
```

Comment: I got a RuntimeError "dictionary changed size during iteration". 

I had more success with: 
```key_list = list(session.keys())
    for key in key_list:
        session.pop(key)```

Answer (score 28):

As pointed out in [Jerry Unkhaptay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37022695/8554766), as well as in corresponding [Flask documentation section](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/views/#logout), you can simply do:

```py
from flask import session

session.clear()
```

Though, as, fairly, pointed out in comment, by [alejandro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7656369/alejandro):

> If you are also using flashed messages in your application, you should consider that flashed messages are stored in the `session` and can, therefore, be erased before they are flashed if you clear the `session`.

My suggestion is to take advantage of list comprehension:

```py
[session.pop(key) for key in list(session.keys())]
```

it is essentially the same `for` loop as in [TheF1rstPancake's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37035256/8554766), though a one-liner. We can remove everything, except flashed messages, from `session` (or add any other conditions, for that matter) quite easily, like so:

```py
[session.pop(key) for key in list(session.keys()) if not key.startswith('_')]
```

Answer (score 0):

As an additional option, if you're using the `flask_login` package, all you have to do is call `logout_user` in the context of a request.

The `logout_user` function pops the session key as mentioned in other answers, while also cleaning up the `remember` cookie and forcing a reload of the user in the `login_manager`.  It also sends a `logged-out` signal (if signal handling is important in your app).

```
from flask_login import logout_user
logout_user()
```

Comment: Incorrect. Upon inspection of the source code behind logout_user(),  it only pops _user_id, _fresh, _id session key values. Therefore, any other session data stored by your own code would still be unpopped.

Comment: The question is asking about how to clear the SecureSessionCookie, which this does.  If you have added a bunch of other session data on your own with some other logic, of course you have to do some other cleanup separately, Flask wouldn’t know about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pop and put it to `g`, you can try:

```py
from flask import g, session

my_value_list = ('sys_info', 'msg')
[setattr(g, s_k, session.pop(s_k)) for s_k in my_value_list if s_k in session.keys()]
```

Answer (score 0):

TO use *session.clear()* you first need to set up your session environment in **/home/username/www/flask_app.py**

It looks something like this below. Notice how I import Session with a capital **S***ession*

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import annotations

from datetime import timedelta
from flask import Flask
from flask_session.__init__ import Session

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = "www.mslscript.com"
app.secret_key = 'adsfkljasdfjsd982134ifdh434df4890g'
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = True
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
app.config['SESSION_FILE_THRESHOLD'] = 250   # 500 is default
app.config['PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME'] = timedelta(hours=10)
Session(app)

from website.views import views
from website.auth import auth

app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/')
app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix='/')
```

**website** is a directory with the *views.py* and *auth.py* files which contain the line:

```py
auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__, template_folder='templates', static_folder='static')
```

Which I assume you recognize as also having the line

`@auth.route('/login.html', methods=['GET', 'POST'])`

Inside this `auth.py` and `views.py` or `__init__.py` you can use the  line `from flask import session` and therefore `session.clear()` and `session['username'] = 'Ashburry'` but `session.pop(key, None)` is the standard convention we have come to agree on; atleast only if you use `flash(f"hello {session['username']}")` *or just* `flash()`

I host my website on PythonAnywhere.com so it is easier for me to setup the server than having to use the app.run() command manually, with the setup included. If you are not using **PythonAnywhere.com** you cannot copy/paste this code you will have to take from it what you need and adapt it to your own `app.run('127.0.0.1', 1234)`