# how to remove session flask python3

Tags: python, flask

I used this request

```
GET /logout HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: th,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: session=eyJ1c2VyIjoiYSJ9.DZun3A.LwCROrj6GQicP1v063cYcItu8SQ;
Connection: close
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

I used `session.clear()` in flask python3 i got responds like

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 4
Set-Cookie: session=; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT; Max-Age=0; Path=/
Server: Werkzeug/0.12.2 Python/3.6.3
Date: Tue, 27 Mar 2018 10:18:30 GMT
```

It just set a new cookies. Then i use old cookies before set a new one, but i still got old session how to remove old session?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to do it by this way:

```
@app.route("/logout/", methods=['GET'])
def logout():
    session.pop('google_token', None)
    session.pop('expires_in', 0)
    session.pop('timer', 0)
    session.pop('csrf_token', '')
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

Of course, in your case variables which are stored in session can be different.

More info is [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27747578/how-do-i-clear-a-flask-session).

Comment: i tried `session.pop('user', None)` and i got same responds. After that i change value of `session['user']` I got a responds that change session ID.i used new session id `session['user']` has changed value, but if i use old session id i got old value of `session['user']`