# How can I cycle through sessions in flask?

Tags: python, flask, session

I have been wondering how I could cycle through sessions. I want to make a system that clears all sessions with the id variable set to the current session id upon going to a specific URL. How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I clear a flask session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27747578/how-do-i-clear-a-flask-session)

Answer (score 1):

In my projects (not in production, of course) I used something like:

```py
@app.route('/clear/')
def clear_session():
    session.clear()
    return redirect('/')
```